# eliminar bordes a imagen con php

Tags: php, imagen, php8

hola tengo el siguiente codigo con el que creo una imagen con php.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng ( $im );
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor ( 512, 512 ); // new wigth and height
imagealphablending($new_image , false);
imagesavealpha($new_image , true);
imagecopyresampled ( $new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512, imagesx ( $image ), imagesy ( $image ) );
$image = $new_image;

// saving
imagealphablending($image , false);
imagesavealpha($image , true);
imagepng($image, "../$Pag_web/imagenes_aplicacion/512x512_logo_app.png");
```

La cuestión es que la imagen que suben los usuarios es cuadrada y quisiera que al momento de  copiarla a png, le pudiera colocar los bordes redondos, existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Entonces no es eliminar los bordes, es redondear las esquinas. No se puede hacer esto sobre un PNG, estos son rectangulares siempre. Lo que puedes hacer es generar la ilusión de que tiene bordes redondeados, colocando una transparencia en las esquinas.

Comment: Puedes añadirlo dentro de una etiqueta img, sino la tienes y luego darle el estilo con css o boostrap

Comment: como podría darle la transparencia en las esquinas? la imagen se mantendrá en el server asi que no puedo usar ccs ni etiquetas img, pero eso de colocarle transparencia en las esquinas me sirve, si me podrías apoyar con un ejemplo así lo adapto a mi proyecto.

Comment: Sugerencia antes de salvar la imagen puedes dibujar una circunferencia de radio 1/2 de la amplitud, poner un color al exterior de la circunferencia, asignando pixel a pixel y finalmente definir ese color como transparente

Comment: amigo suena buenísimo, me podrías colaboras con un ejemplo?